# Pushing no-code changes from TEST to LIVE environments in Sharetribe Flex

Tags: sharetribe, sharetribe-flex

From [Sharetribe Flex environments workflow documentation](https://www.sharetribe.com/docs/concepts/flex-environments/#workflow-between-the-three-environments):

> no-code changes are made in Test, and get pushed from Test to Live

My question is: how do I actually push these changes?

For example: lets say, I've modified landing page (in `TEST` environment), does "push" mean that I have to manually replicate changes I've made in `LIVE` environment, or there is some way for me to transfer no-code changes from `TEST` to `LIVE` (using Flex console or cli)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Console has a "Copy changes to..." button in your test environment in the Content tab. Clicking that button will allow you to select the environment where you want to copy your changes (live or dev) and determine which changes to copy over.

Comment: It looks these buttons appear only after live environment is enabled (I am yet to enable live env and these buttons are not present in my flex console).

Comment: That sounds curious – the button should show up in your Test environment when you have Test and Dev environments present. If you are still not seeing the button, you can reach out to our support team in your Console and we can take a closer look at what might be going on!